# Bootstrap 4: Large margin on right of col-md-6 div

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm writing an application in Angular with Bootstrap 4. I'm trying to get two standard col-md-6 divs to appear side-by-side. The first one contains the table, and the second one contains that white line you see below. I inspected one of them, and it appears that there is a large margin to the right of the div, as in the screenshot. Changing the margin in developer tools has no effect. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
<div class="mainPanel">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <app-sidebar-cmp></app-sidebar-cmp>

  <div class="dash-component">
    <div class="details-layout">
      <h2>Study Detail: {{study.title}}</h2>
      <!-- table -->
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card-body light-table table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td>{{study.title}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Date:</td>
                <td>{{study.dateTime}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Date Received:</td>
                <td>{{study.receivedDateTime}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Scanner:</td>
                <td (click)="viewScanner(study.scanner._id)">{{study.scanner.name}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Modality:</td>
                <td>{{study.modality}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- images -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div *ngFor="let image of image" class="col-md-12">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of the misbehaving div]

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Think you might of wanted to use `<div class="row">` instead of `col-md-12`

Comment: @penleychan Beauty; thanks

Comment: @AaronVerones what you wan to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

> Think you might of wanted to use  instead of col-md-12

This fixed it. Thank you @penleychan!